# What is the called order of the handlers in martini?

Tags: go, martini

About golang martini

- We can add middlewares using m.Use(). Of course, "Middleware Handlers are invoked in the order that they are added".
- In addition, a handler can also be added by router like r.Get("/", handler).
- Sometimes, we also need a handler be called after the router handler. That is a handler is called before something is written to ResponseWriter.

So, how to order of presentation of these handlers? I can not get solution is martini's document.

Comment: The router handler should be writing to the ResponseWriter.  Therefore, you need a middleware to access the ResponseWriter before the route writes to it.  I'd suggest negroni (https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni) for more idiomatic middleware handling.

Comment: Martini is now abandoned. Try Gin instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, middlewares in Martini and others are called in the order they are defined: first the ones added with use, then the route middlewares, then the route handler.

Here is the middleware example given by the martini documentation:

```
// log before and after a request
m.Use(func(c martini.Context, log *log.Logger){
    log.Println("before a request")

    c.Next()

    log.Println("after a request")
})
```

According to this, if you have middlewares A and B and the route R, then the call chain will be something like that:

```
func A() {
    // Do things before B

    func B() {
        // Do things before R

        func R() {
            // Do things in R
        } ()

        // Do things after R
    }()

    // Do things after B
}
```

So depending of what you need, you will need to add code in a middleware before or after the `Next()`  call.